# press enter keyboard in laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

In Laravel dusk, how do I type text and press enter keyboard in it?

[image]

My input field needs to press enter keyboard to be able to add more than 1 item at there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$browser->keys('selector', 'element1', '{enter}', 'otwell', '{enter}');
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Toàn Âu Thế thank you so much, it did help me get some pointer.
I'm doing it with "$browser->keys('.input-tag', '{enter}')"