# Using keyboard in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-dusk

Laravel versions:

- "laravel/framework": "^6.2"
- "laravel/dusk": "^5.9"

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/dusk#using-the-keyboard) about using the keyboard in Laravel Dusk shows the following syntax:

```php
$browser->keys('selector', ['{shift}', 'taylor'], 'otwell');
// or
$browser->keys('.app', ['{command}', 'j']);
```

In my code, I have:

```php
public function test_project_can_be_created()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser
                ->loginAs($this->user)
                ->visit('/')
                ->click('a[href="'.route('projects.index').'"]')
                ->click('a[href="'.route('projects.create').'"]')
                ->keys('#app', ['{enter}']) // this is line 106
                ->type('project[name]', $this->faker->word)
                ->click('@submit');
        }); // this is line 109
    }
```

What I want to achieve, is just simply pressing the "ENTER" key in the Browser. However...

When I run `php artisan dusk` I get the following error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ProjectsTest::test_project_can_be_created
ErrorException: Array to string conversion

/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php:333 // https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php#L333
/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/InteractsWithElements.php:107 // https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5.0/src/Concerns/InteractsWithElements.php#L107
/tests/Browser/ProjectsTest.php:106
/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:68
/tests/Browser/ProjectsTest.php:109
```

Am I missing something? Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: I also don't know why on a related answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405564/7784399 is the accepted answer, because those `{enter}`'s are not even a string..

Comment: Have you tried `'{enter}'`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes, look at my code. I've tried both `->keys('#app', ['{enter}'])` and `->keys('#app', '{enter}')`